# Mudblazor Razor page is loading more than one time

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I am working on Blazor Web Assembly using Mudblazor. OnInitializedAsync method is being called only one time, but why razor page is rendered two times. Second question is value of message variable is displayed in MudTextField after 2nd iteration of razor page. I have used OnKeyPressed event, and I see that after each key pressed, razor page is rendered again. I will be thankful for suggestion of these issues

```
@page "/Test"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
<h1> @message </h1>
<MudTextField Required="true"
              OnKeyPress="OnKeyPressed"
              Immediate="true"
              Margin="Margin.Dense"
              T="Int64"
@bind-Value="@Barcode"
              Label=""
              Variant="Variant.Outlined"
              Adornment="Adornment.Start"
              AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Person">
</MudTextField>
@if (Barcode > 0)
{
    <MudTextField Label="message" @bind-Value="@message" Variant="Variant.Outlined"></MudTextField>
}
@code {
    public Int64 Barcode { get; set; }
    string message;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        message = "Hello";
        Barcode = 0;
    }

    public async void OnKeyPressed(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == "Enter")
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
            message = "Hello again";
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Delay method, to change text value of MudTextField afte 4 seconds.

There are some helpful links for Blazor server applications but couldn't find for Blazor web assembly applications.

Comment: The page will be re-rendered whenever bound value changes, when an event fires and many other situations. Question is how is the page being rendered multiple times causing you a problem?

Comment: Problem is I see that all the bind variables are set to new values (I have debugged the code). These variables are bind to MudTextFields. But new values are not displayed in MudTextFields. I have to press Enter key one more time and then all the code executes again and MudTextFields display the accurate values. For every time I have to press Enter key two times to execute the code two times to display values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created identical razor page and seperate out the code behind logic in seperate class. On Enter key pressed event, I call alternate razor component. I don't know it's a better solution, but for me it is ok. If someone else find other solution, I will appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Set `Immediate` to false. The immediate property is defined in the [Docs](https://mudblazor.com/api/textfield#pages) as

> If true, the input will update the Value immediately on typing.
> If false, the Value is updated only on Enter.

Comment: Unfortunately it also doesn't work. It is still working by pressing the Enter key two times. I am using many async functions and await commands. First time data is being bind by API calls in different lists etc. Could this be a reason.

Comment: Someone help please.